# Pass parameters to Voice Recorder

Tags: android, voice-recording

I need to record Audio, And I would be pleased to use Built in Voice Recorder, but it would be nice to pass it parameters : Specific Path, Specific Quatlity, etc.

Is it posible?

I like this solution because code is very short:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, AUDIO_RECORDING);
```

Here I have an example to copy file to specific location:

[How can I specify the output file's folder when calling RECORD_SOUND_ACTION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305427/how-can-i-specify-the-output-files-folder-when-calling-record-sound-action)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not posible. If you need to customize it, you will need to develop your own activity. You can work with google Sample !

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html